# Link Author's Website in Author Bio

Tags: author, links

I'm wondering if there is a way to link a website in the Author's bio under Wordpress Users? I have tried this code but to no avail:
`<a href="sampleWebsiteURLHere" title="Sample title here">click here</a>.`

It is being printed out as a literal string and not as a hyperlink.

Comment: As far as I can tell, nothing in WordPress core prevents the use of HTML in author bios. This means that your theme is likely escaping it on output, preventing HTML. Did you develop your theme yourself? Or did you download/purchase it from someone else? If you didn't develop it then you'll likely need to speak to the theme author about how to get around this.